# Как исправить ошибку при инициализации realm

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

Приложение вылетает при обработке Realm.getInstance(config) Ошибка:
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'TaskRealmObjClass.id' has been made optional.

```
open class TaskRealmObjClass(
var id: Int? = 0,
var date_start:String? = null,
var date_finish:String? = null,
var name:String? = null,
var description:String? = null
): RealmObject()

class NewTask: AppCompatActivity() {
private fun saveTask(){

    Realm.init(this)
    var config = RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("database.realm").build()
    val realm = Realm.getInstance(config)

    realm.beginTransaction()
    val taskId = giveId(realm)
    val taskName = etTaskName.text.toString().trim()
    val taskTime = sTaskTime.selectedItem.toString().trim()
    val taskTimeStart = dateTimeToMillis(selectedDate, splitTaskTime(taskTime)[0]).toString()
    val taskTimeFinish = dateTimeToMillis(selectedDate, splitTaskTime(taskTime)[1]).toString()
    val taskDescription = etTaskDescription.text.toString().trim()

    if(taskName.isEmpty()){
        etTaskName.error = "Введите название дела"
        return
    }

    val taskObject = TaskRealmObjClass(taskId,taskTimeStart,taskTimeFinish,taskName,taskDescription)
    realm.copyToRealm(taskObject)
    realm.commitTransaction()
}

private fun giveId(realm: Realm):Int{
    realm.beginTransaction()
    if(!realm.isEmpty) {
        val unique = realm.where(TaskRealmObjClass::class.java).distinct("id").findAll()
        realm.commitTransaction()
        return unique.size + 1
    }else{
        realm.commitTransaction()
        return 0
    }
```

Файл build.gradle

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidapp.diaryapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding false
    }
    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.8.11.1'


}
```

Файл build.gradle(Project)

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.3.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас сменилась схема БД. Надо или миграцию писать или чистить данные приложения через системные настройки оного.